# Render header with jwt to another page with node js

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have create a post request to send the JW token if the user is correct log in. The header appears with the Auth Token but I can't pass the token to another page. Here is my Login POST with render to another page:

If I then try to make then the user clicks on the tab to Create a User, I send a private get request which verifies the Token. However, the header doens't have the token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb4qD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ut54.png)

The token value is always empty on the verifyJWT function and I don't know why. If I do a console.log(req.headers) it never has the auth-token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO0If.png)

Comment: Please 1. include all code as written code in the question, not as images or links, and 2. for things that have to be images, use the `![label goes here](URL goes here)` syntax to embed images directly - the `!` makes the image appear in the post, instead of a link to the image :)

Comment: Could you please type your code in the question itself instead of the pictures, also how are setting the token, can you put that code too.